# JSP and jQuery - Adding onclick function to variable number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Given the following jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${cartdata.cart }" var="t" varStatus="i">
    <div class="horizontal boxShadow section">
        <h2 class="horizontal">${ t.hotel.name }</h2>
        <p>Start: ${ t.stay.start }  End: ${ t.stay.end }</p>
        <p class="horizontal">Number of rooms: <input type="text" disabled="true" value="${t.hotel.numRooms }" id="res${i.index }" />   <input type="button" value="Edit" id="resbut${i.index }" /></p>
        <p class="horizontal">Room Price:$ ${t.hotel.roomPrice } Cost:$ ${t.cost } </p>
        <div id="roomStatus${i.index}"></div>
    </div>
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to add functions to each button that will enable me to edit the value in each ID = `res+${i.index}`text input.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var length = ${cartdata.cart.size()};
    for (i = 0; i<length; i++){
        $('#resbut' + i).click(function() {
            $("res" + i).prop("disabled", false);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is the exact problem you are facing? What did you try so far and failed??

Comment: The question has been answered, but it should be obvious that what I tried so far is what I have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about giving them ids. It makes things overly complicated. Give them classes instead. Find the related item by traversing the DOM.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(".resbut").on("click", function (event) {
    var $resbut = $(this);
    var $res = $resbut.parents(".section").find(".res");
    $res.prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: Interesting. What is `.section` here?

Comment: @user3591541 — A class selector. It will match `<div class="horizontal boxShadow section">`

Comment: Worked like a charm(albeit by setting disabled to false, not true). Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable/disable the input corresponding to a button you can try this:

```
   $(':button').click(function(){
        var $parent=$(this).parent();
        $parent.find(':text').attr('disabled',false);
        $('p').not($parent).find(':text').attr('disabled',true);
    });
```